# Get Cell value from selected row gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, selected

I have a GridView that has 7 columns. 6 of the columns have LinkButtons.

What I want to do is,  get the data value that is in the 1st column and put that in a Label elsewhere on  my page when one of those LinkButons is clicked.

For example the first column has a value that looks like this: *01:00 - 02:00.*

Here is what I have so far: *My GridView is named gvappts*

I have added this property:`OnRowDataBound="gvappts_DataBound"`

And inside gvappts on one of my LinkButtons I have added *Command* and *Command Arguments*:`<asp:LinkButton id="lbd1" runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("Day1"))%>' CommandName="GetData" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>`

Because I want to Select the current row.

In my .cs I have this:

```
protected void gvappts_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "GetData")
        {
            //Get rowindex
            int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            //Get Row
            GridViewRow gvr = gvappts.Rows[rowindex];
            //Set the label value
            lblTimeSelected.Text = gvr.Cells[0].Text;
        }
    }
```

I do not get any errors when clicking the buttons, but no value is returned. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Why not bind the same source column to `CommandArgument` that you bound to the 1st column of grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
 GridViewRow gvr = gvappts.Rows[rowindex];
 Label myLabel  = gvr.FindControl("MyLabel Id") as Label ;
 lblTimeSelected.Text = myLabel.Text;
```